# Remove list if it's contained in another list within the same nested list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a nested list:

```
regions = [[1,2,3],[3,4],[1,3,4],[1,2,3,5]]
```

I want to remove every list in this nested list which is contained in another one, i.e., [3,4] contained in [1,3,4] and [1,2,3] contained in [1,2,3,5], so the result is:

```
result = [[1,3,4],[1,2,3,5]]
```

So far I'm doing:

```
regions_remove = []
for i,reg_i in enumerate(regions):
    for j,reg_j in enumerate(regions):
        if j != i and list(set(reg_i)-set(reg_j)) == []:
regions_remove.append(reg_i)
regions = [list(item) for item in set(tuple(row) for row in regions) -
               set(tuple(row) for row in regions_remove)]
```

And I've got: `regions = [[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 3, 4]]` and this is a solution, but I'd like to know what's the most pythonic solution?

(sorry for not posting my entire code before, I'm a new to this...

Comment: What is not working with your current attempt?

Comment: Show some effort. This is not a free coding site.

Comment: list comprehension would be the most pythonic way here :) ! Please add an example of what you already tryed to do

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: @vash. This is python. Just import instead of manifesting.

Comment: @jeannej why would a list-comprehension be the most Pythonic?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stack oveflow... I've updated my question with my solution and I hope you can help me now.

Comment: @mralarcon alright, you indeed came up with a solution! I posted an answer which uses python's built-in function, I think it would be clearer for a Python user than what you proposed. Do not forget to upvote any usefull answers and to accept your prefered one. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely overlooking a simpler route, but this approach works

*list comprehension*

```
from itertools import product

l = [[1,2,3],[3,4],[1,3,4],[1,2,3,5]]
bad = [i for i in l for j in l if i != j if tuple(i) in product(j, repeat = len(i))]
final = [i for i in l if i not in bad]
```

Expanded explanation

```
from itertools import product
l = [[1,2,3],[3,4],[1,3,4],[1,2,3,5]]
bad = []
for i in l:
    for j in l:
        if i != j:
            if tuple(i) in product(j, repeat = len(i)):
                bad.append(i)

final = [i for i in l if i not in bad]
print(final)
```

> ```
> [[1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 5]]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with list comprehension and `all()` function :

```
nested_list = [[1,2,3],[3,4],[1,3,4],[1,2,3,5],[2,5]]
result = list(nested_list)      #makes a copy of the initial list
for l1 in nested_list:          #list in nested_list
    rest = list(result)         #makes a copy of the current result list
    rest.remove(l1)             #the list l1 will be compared to every other list (so except itself)
    for l2 in rest:             #list to compare
        if all([elt in l2 for elt in l1]): result.remove(l1)
                                #if all the elements of l1 are in l2 (then all() gives True), it is removed
```

returns:

```
[[1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 5]]
```

---

**Further help**

all() built-in function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all

copy a list: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-list

list comprehension: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python